# Keyboard Event trigger on button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, typescript

```js
add(){
  var newEvent = null; 
  try 
  {
    newEvent = document.createEvent("KeyEvents"); 
    newEvent.initKeyEvent("keypress", true, true, window,false, false, false, false, 0, 32); 
  }
  catch(ex) 
  {
    console.log(ex); 
    newEvent = document.createEvent("KeyboardEvent"); 
    newEvent.initKeyboardEvent('keypress', true, true, window, false, false, false, false, 32, 0); 
  }
          // e.preventDefault(); 
              document.getElementById('surname').dispatchEvent(newEvent);
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="surname" name="surname" placeholder="आडनाव" [(ngModel)]="surName">
<button class="btn btn-primary" (click)="add();" id="add" >Fire</button>
```

```js
add(){
  var newEvent = null; 
  try 
  { 
    newEvent = document.createEvent("KeyEvents"); 
    newEvent.initKeyEvent("keypress", true, true,window,false, false, false, false, 0, 32); 
   }
   catch(ex) 
   { 
    console.log("aa ",ex); 
    newEvent = document.createEvent("KeyboardEvent"); 
    newEvent.initKeyboardEvent('keypress', true, true, window, false, false, false, false, 32, 0); 
    }
}
```

```html
<button class="btn btn-primary" (click)="add();" id="add" >Fire</button>
```

Above code is not working...didnot fire keyevent,
I want to fire keypress event (SpaceBar) on button click in JQuery or javascript or angular 2.

Comment: Yes, and where is the problem? What did you try?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/596481/is-it-possible-to-simulate-key-press-events-programmatically

Comment: @Lain Its not working for spacebar (keycode 32)

Comment: Could try keyup instead, keypress does not support all keys.

Comment: still same issue occurs